# No Scope registered for scope name 'job' running a Spring Batch job with Annotation Config only

Tags: spring-batch

I have to create batch jobs that need to create some configuration beans depending in the job parameters, So I can't instantiate them in the start of the application.

I tried to follow some of the examples I found but none worked. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The Job configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    /***
     * This job will create/update the resources in AWS accordingly with the
     * configuration provided.
     * 
     * @return the job
     */
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("NetworkJob")
    @Primary
    public Job createJob() {
    return jobs.get("Start Job").start(dummyTasklet()).build();
    }

    /***
     * Create a step to verify if a service role exists or to create it if not.
     * 
     * @return the step
     */
    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step dummyTasklet() {
    return steps.get("Dummy").tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        log.info("And I run ... ");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }).build();
    }

}
```

And some JobScope beans:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class GitConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("GITPath")
    @JobScope
    public String getGitTemporaryPath() {
    return "/tmp/path";
    }

    @JobScope
    @Bean
    public Git getCustomerGitRepository(@Value("#{jobParameters[customerRepository]}") String customerRepository,
        @Value("#{jobParameters[customerBranch]}") String customerBranch,
        @Value("#{jobParameters[vaultSecretPath]}") String vaultSecretPath,
        @Value("#{jobParameters[id]}") String id) {

    return Git.cloneRepository().setURI(customerRepository)
        .setDirectory(new File(getGitTemporaryPath() + id)).setBranch(customerBranch)
        .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(Git repository) {
       PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
       val path = repository.getRepository().getWorkTree().getAbsolutePath()
        + "file.yml";
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(path));
       return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `EnableBatchProcessing` annotation automatically imports the `JobScope` and `StepScope`. Looks like you use case can be addressed with Spring Profiles. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: No. I can't use spring profiles because I want to execute a batch process using "Custom" configuration that it's stored in external Git Repos. This is part of a PaaS solution that I execute the process with some configuration. If not using the propertySource probably I need to create a JobExecutionContext and start storing there the info ... is more hard to read this way because I will have some large set of data, If I can create a propertySourcePlaceholder to load each configuration file it would be great.

Comment: I got it working. Looks like I can't have in the same Configuration files JobScoped beans and non JobScoped beans. And also you shouldn't have the @JobScope anotation in the Job bean.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. Looks like I can't have in the same Configuration files JobScoped beans and non JobScoped beans. And also you shouldn't have the @JobScope anotation in the Job bean. – Hugo Dias 19 hours ago